# How to groupby splitted text and count their count using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Station':['001ABC006','002ABD008','005ABX009','007ABY010','001ABC006','002ABD008'],
    'Trains Passing':[55,56,59,96,95,96],
    'Destination':['MRK','MRK','MRS','MTS','KPS','KPS']

})
```

I need to Split the **Station** text from '001ABC006' to 'ABC' and create a list. Count only the values present in the list. Also group by destination. How could I do it?

Output:

```
  StationId ABC ABD ABX ABY
  MRK       1   1   0   0
  MRS       0   0   1   0
  MTS       0   0   0   1
  KPS       1   1   0   0
```

Comment: Try to resis changing your question once asked, if you need to, please ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a cross tabulation and the link below shows several ways to do this.
**See**: [how-to-pivot-a-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/2336654)

#### `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Destination, df.Station.str.replace('\d', ''))

Station      ABC  ABD  ABX  ABY
Destination                    
KPS            1    1    0    0
MRK            1    1    0    0
MRS            0    0    1    0
MTS            0    0    0    1
```

---

#### Replace digits

```
df.Station.str.replace('\d', '').value_counts()

ABC    2
ABD    2
ABY    1
ABX    1
Name: Station, dtype: int64
```

---

#### `findall`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

i, r = pd.factorize(re.findall('(?i)([a-z]+)', '|'.join(df.Station)))
pd.Series(np.bincount(i), r)

ABC    2
ABD    2
ABX    1
ABY    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: It works can you give it in this format str[3:6] if possible?

Comment: Just replace `df.Station.str.replace('\d', '')` with `df.Station.str[3:6]`.  And accept @Zero's answer since it is his idea you are going with.  Your changing the question shouldn't take away from him giving you the answer you needed.  By all rights, you should've asked a new question.  But that's all fine, I'd just feel better if you selected his answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

Updated

```
In [180]: pd.crosstab(df.Destination, df.Station.str[3:6])
Out[180]:
Station      ABC  ABD  ABX  ABY
Destination                    
KPS            1    1    0    0
MRK            1    1    0    0
MRS            0    0    1    0
MTS            0    0    0    1
```

You could use

```
In [160]: pd.DataFrame([df.Station.str[3:6].value_counts().to_dict()])
Out[160]:
   ABC  ABD  ABX  ABY
0    2    2    1    1
```

Or,

```
In [149]: df.Station.str[3:6].value_counts().to_frame().T
Out[149]:
         ABC  ABD  ABX  ABY
Station    2    2    1    1
```

---

Details

```
In [162]: df.Station.str[3:6]
Out[162]:
0    ABC
1    ABD
2    ABX
3    ABY
4    ABC
5    ABD
Name: Station, dtype: object

In [163]: df.Station.str[3:6].value_counts()
Out[163]:
ABC    2
ABD    2
ABX    1
ABY    1
Name: Station, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If there is another column and how can I groupby from it?

Comment: please check the question now

Comment: @YogeshSP this post has been updated.  Please accept this answer instead.